# std::string and UTF-8 encoded unicode

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8

If I understand well, it is possible to use both string and wstring to store UTF-8 text.

- With char, ASCII characters take a single byte, some chinese characters take 3 or 4, etc. Which means that `str[3]` doesn't necessarily point to the 4th character.
- With `wchar_t` same thing, but the minimal amount of bytes used per characters is always 2 (instead of 1 for `char`), and a 3 or 4 byte wide character will take 2 `wchar_t`.

Right ?

So, what if I want to use `string::find_first_of()` or `string::compare()`, etc with such a weirdly encoded string ? Will it work ? Does the string class handle the fact that characters have a variable size ? Or should I only use them as dummy feature-less byte arrays, in which case I'd rather go for a `wchar_t[]` buffer.

If `std::string` doesn't handle that, second question: are there libraries providing string classes that could handle that UTF-8 encoding so that `str[3]` actually points to the 3rd character (which would be a byte array from length 1 to 4) ?

Comment: Note that even if `str[3]` was the fourth code point, that's not necessarily the fourth user-perceived character.

Comment: @delnan _Ok sorry (I just picked one example article about wchar_t, Windows and UTF-16). Since it was too late to edit I've deleted the comment, and here is back the part without the "controversial" link:_ I think that the size of `wchar_t` is implementation-defined, so _not_ always 2 bytes. Moreover (IIRC) Windows uses it to store something like UTF-16, not UTF-8. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about Unicode. Unicode uses 32 bits to represent a character. However since that is wasting memory there are more compact encodings. UTF-8 is one such encoding. It assumes that you are using byte units and it maps Unicode characters to 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes. UTF-16 is another that is using words as units and maps Unicode characters to 1 or 2 words (2 or 4 bytes).
You can use both encoding with both string and wchar_t. UTF-8 tends to be more compact for english text/numbers.

Some things will work regardless of encoding and type used (compare). However all functions that need to understand one character will be broken. I.e the 5th character is not always the 5th entry in the underlying array. It might look like it's working with certain examples but It will eventually break.
string::compare will work but do not expect to get alphabetical ordering. That is language dependent.
string::find_first_of will work for some but not all. Long string will likely work just because they are long while shorter ones might get confused by character alignment and generate very hard to find bugs.

Best thing is to find a library that handles it for you and ignore the type underneath (unless you have strong reasons to pick one or the other).

Comment: *Unicode uses 32 bits to represent a character.* => really depends what you call a character. Unicode defines Code Points (integers) and Graphemes (sequences of integers, generally of size 1), and people tend to associate "character" with "grapheme" because it is the visual entity that appears on the screen.

Comment: _Unicode uses 32 bits to represent a character._
This is incorrect! Unicode does **not** use any amount of bits to represent a character. Unicode is purely abstract. It assigns a number to each character. It does not mandate how many bits to represent that character. The encodings are not "more compact" ways to represent the characters, they **are** the ways to represent the characters. See https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 2):

You can't handle Unicode with std::string or any other tools from Standard Library. Use external library such as: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct for those:
...Which means that str[3] doesn't necessarily point to the 4th character...only use them as dummy feature-less byte arrays...
string of C++ can only handle ascii characters. This is different from the String of Java, which can handle Unicode characters. You can store the encoding result (bytes) of Chinese characters into string (char in C/C++ is just byte), but this is meaningless as string just treat the bytes as ascii chars, so you cannot use string function to process it. 
wstring may be something you need.

There is something that should be clarified. UTF-8 is just an encoding method for Unicode characters (transforming characters from/to byte format).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What i wanted to know is what methods of the string class would still work when using an UTF-8 encoded text.

Comment: -1 `std::string` stores `char`s. But that doesn't mean it's limited to ASCII, it just means it doesn't know anything about encodings, so you can use it for any encoding (and consequently screw everything up if you're not careful). And Java's string is a UTF-16 array, so `str[3]` isn't necessarily the fourth code point either.

Comment: @delnan Please down-vote after fully going through my answer. I have stated this "You can store the encoding result (bytes) of Chinese characters into string (char in C/C++ is just byte), but this is meaningless as string just treat the bytes as ascii chars, so you cannot use string function to process it. "  I said "string of C++ can only handle ascii characters." not "string of C++ can only store ascii characters."  HANDLE is different from STORE. string functions will be meaningless when you just use it to store bytes, that's why I used HANDLE. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to elaborate on the difference between "store" and "handle", because I can't find any operation that works with ASCII but not with UTF-8 encoded strings (UTF-16 might be a different matter) - substring search, for example, [works just fine](http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.validation). Indexing, iterating or selecting a substring will use code units rather than code points, but the same is true of the Java strings which you claim handle Unicode.

Comment: @delnan Actually substr of string is not search, just operation on ascii character or in other words byte. Can string::find work with UTF-8 encoded strings? such as using string::find to find a Chinese/Japanese character  in one string storing the UTF-8 encoded bytes. Obviously, it cannot work. That's why I use HANDLE not STORE.    It's really hard for me to understand why you down-voted my answer and gave such comments before finishing my answer. Of course, HANDLE is not accurate enough but I realized that and elaborated after that sentence.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I thought -- and still think after re-reading it right now -- that it contains very little useful information and spreads several falsehoods/myths. Have you read the "UTF8 Everywhere" FAQ entry I linked to? The substring search algorithm (i.e. `std::string::find`) for UTF-8 *is the same* as substring search for single byte encodings. I'm not making this up. It follows from how UTF-8 spreads code points across several bytes, this is explained at http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.validation

Comment: @delnan Yes, std::string::find can work for UTF-8 encoded, but conceptually just in byte mode not character mode. What you pass in is also just an array of bytes. For "because I can't find any operation that works with ASCII but not with UTF-8 encoded strings", may be string::find is not a good example, then how about operator[]? Does this work for string storing UTF-8 encoded byte? Is the result meaningful?

Comment: **I already addressed that**. It operates on code units (which are bytes for UTF-8), so it's somewhat meaningful but you don't get a code point as result. However, (this too I already mentioned) Java string indexing *also* works on code units (only it works on UTF-16 code units, but that's **not** the same as code points), Either Java strings don't handle Unicode or std::string does. And yes, both these cases (and all others) it doesn't work because `std::string` did something special, it worked because the designers of UTF-8 were smart. But the end result is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36976/discussion-between-delnan-and-jackyzhu)